# FluentNHibernate mapping; Unable to map double or decimal with scale/precision

Tags: .net, database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm working first time with **FluentNHibernate**, trying to map classes to **SQL Express** database. In general it works, but I'm unable to map **Double or Decimal** property types to specific **scale/precision**. Below shows result for a single property that I tested over and over with **SchemaUpdate.Execute**. In no case was I able to get it to work.

Would be really helpful to hear some explanation to the mappings that does not work as I expect (2-8)?

```
// Ok mappings:
```

**1) Decimal**:  Map(Function(x) x.Balance) **>>** Decimal(19, 5)

```
// Mappings "errors":
```

**2) Double**:  Map(Function(x) x.Balance).CustomSqlType("decimal")  **>>** Decimal(18,0)
- Why 0 precision is the default mapping here?

**3) Double**:  Map(Function(x) x.Balance) **>>** Float , 
But; when running **SchemaValidator** after: 
 **HibernateException**: Wrong column type in FnhDb.dbo.Account for column Balance. Found: float, Expected DOUBLE PRECISION

**4) Decimal**:  Map(Function(x) x.Balance).Scale(9).Precision(2)  **>>** 
**SqlException**: The scale (9) for column 'Balance' must be within the range 0 to 2.

**5,6) Decimal or Double**:  Map(Function(x) x.Balance).Scale(9).Precision(2).CustomSqlType("numeric")  **>>** numeric(18,0)

**7,8) Decimal or Double**:  Map(Function(x) x.Balance).Scale(9).Precision(2).CustomSqlType("decimal")  **>>** Decimal(18,0)

---

**EDIT:** 
I include code and hbm.xml (export) for case (4) here:

```
Public Class AccountMap
    Inherits ClassMap(Of Account)

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        Id(Function(x) x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity()
        Map(Function(x) x.Balance).Scale(9).Precision(2)   
        Map(Function(x) x.Deposits)
        Map(Function(x) x.WithDrawals)
    End Sub
End Class

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="false">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" mutable="true" name="RoboTrader.Account, RoboTrader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`Account`">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Balance" type="System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Balance" precision="2" scale="9" />
    </property>
    <property name="Deposits" type="System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Deposits" />
    </property>
    <property name="WithDrawals" type="System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="WithDrawals" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

**EDIT2:**

Btw, this is not a **VB** issue. I have the exact same problem in a **C#** project. Can it be the **MsSql2008 configuration** that is not compatible with **Sql Express 2008 R2**?

---

**EDIT3:**

```
Option Strict On
```

Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System

```
Public Class Account
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
End Sub

Private _Id As Integer

Private _Balance As Double

Private _Deposits As Integer

Private _WithDrawals As Integer


Public Overridable Property Id() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Id
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _Id = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Overridable Property Balance() As Double
    Get
        Return _Balance
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        _Balance = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Overridable Property Deposits() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Deposits
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _Deposits = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Overridable Property WithDrawals() As Integer
    Get
        Return _WithDrawals
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _WithDrawals = value
    End Set
End Property




End Class
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, your understanding of `Precision` and `Scale` is wrong. `Precision` is always higher than `Scale`. See [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) for a better understanding, which states:

> Precision is the number of digits in a
>   number. Scale is the number of digits
>   to the right of the decimal point in a
>   number. For example, the number 123.45 
>   has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.

In your second example, i.e. `Decimal(18,0)`, 0 is `Scale`, not `Precision`. `Precision` is 18.

Secondly, your mapping should be this:

```
Map(Function(x) x.Balance).CustomSqlType("decimal").Precision(9).Scale(2);
```

If you set `CustomSqlType("decimal")` after setting `Precision` and `Scale`, the settings done by you will be reset.

**EDIT:**
You are using `double` in the declaration, where I think you should use `decimal`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) to know why. `double` is a floating type variable so it is mapped to a `float` by default until you mention otherwise or until the `Precision` is higher than 7. If you change the declaration of `Balance` to `decimal`, you can map the property like this without any problems:

```
Map(Function(x) x.Balance).Precision(9).Scale(2)
```

Comment: Ai.. Thanks! I checked this exact thing (Def. of precision/scale), but must have read it wrong also then..  Well, that leaves me I think with only one question:  How come I'm not able to map a double to Decimal/numeric?  As it will always create a (18,0) column ?

Comment: It depends on how you have declared the `Balance` property in your object. Can you post the POCO object's declaration?

Comment: Ok, I added the whole class above. And now mapping like you said:  Map(Function(x) x.Balance).CustomSqlType("decimal").Precision(9).Scale(2)

Comment: Hmm. Yes I've read a lot of double/decimal discussions. And in this example a decimal property may be appropriate, but shouldn't it in general be possible to map a double to specified precision/scale of decimal/numeric?  Is this considered a no-no to let the ORM or database do this conversion?

Comment: Actually it depends on your object declaration that what field the database/ORM maps your property to. You need to declare it correctly first because that is how Fluent NHibernate works.

Comment: I see. Ok, now I think it all makes sense to me. Cheers! :)